# How do I grep file contents to see if it ends in a newline?

Tags: regex, grep, code-climate

I'm using [CodeClimate's grep engine](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/grep) and I would like a pattern to verify that our code files end with a blank line. I've seen a lot of posts explaining how to count and find blank lines, but I want to specific check EOF.

Comment: Not familiar with this engine but in case you check your files with a command like `grep-engine-command myfile` you could use something like `grep-engine-command <(tail -n1 myfile)`

Comment: Grep operates a line at a time. AFAIK, it doesn't have any visibility to the line break characters themselves.